# How to create remote tar (bash)

Tags: bash, tar, remote-execution

My script is executing the following line:

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@${SUPPORTED_SERVERS[$i]} "gtar -zcvf $TAR_FILE `find $LOCAL_PATH -name *$DATE*`
```

Now, the problem is that `find` command is being executed on the local machine and I need it to be executed on the remote one.

Please help,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$()` rather than backtick ` and additionaly escape it with backslash to avoid executing the command on the local machine:

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@${SUPPORTED_SERVERS[$i]} "gtar -zcvf $TAR_FILE \$(find $LOCAL_PATH -name *$DATE*)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a script, copy it to the server and run that. It may seem pointless now for such a simple thing, but you'll probably thank me later.

Comment: Tried. The result is the same

Comment: I don't think you understand what I meant then. I mean that the ` should be inside the script, so that you don't face this problem.

Comment: I meant the script SHOULD NOT INCLUDE THE SSH IN IT. So you copy the script TO THE SERVER and run it USING SSH.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like such method... Answer #1 worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

When executing a command over SSH, you need to escape any special characters that should not be evaluated locally. Escape the backticks to have them evaluated on the remote server:

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@${SUPPORTED_SERVERS[$i]} "gtar -zcvf $TAR_FILE \`find $LOCAL_PATH -name *$DATE*\`
```

Assuming `$TAR_FILE`, `$LOCAL_PATH` and `$DATE` are local variables, otherwise escape them also. (They would need to exist as environment variables on the remote server)

**Alternative**

Like @RobinGreen points out: It is often better to make a script on the remote server and execute that over SSH.

```
#!/bin/sh
# This is the remote script
# Use positional arguments $1 - $3 and make a tarball
gtar -zcvf $1 $(find $2) -name "*$3*"
```

Call it like this

```
ssh $REMOTE_USER@${SUPPORTED_SERVERS[$i]} "/path/to/remote/script $TAR_FILE $LOCAL_PATH $DATE"
```